# Best Practice with jQuery and AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, security

I have a question about best practices when using jQuery/JavaScript/Ajax. Lets say that I have some tasks and there is a calendar for every task. The User is able to click on a day in a task calendar and book the task at the specific day via AJAX. I have to store the date and the ID of the task somewhere and i am using really bizarre IDs for that such as:

```
<span class="day_field" id="date_13-02-2013_task_4">13.02.2013</span>
```

Then i just attach an listener like this:

```
$('.day_field').on('click',function(){
    var date = $(this).id.split('_')[1];
    var task_id = $(this).id.split('_')[3];
    //place for some validation
    $.post('book_task.php',{task_id: task_id, date: date},function(data){
        //something cool with the result
    });
});
```

My question is: Is this the right way how to do it? I am not pretty sure, because the IDs can be really long + it contains ID in database which is not probably save at all.

Thanks!
T.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use HTML5 data attributes:

```
<span class="day_field" data-date="13-02-2013" data-task="4">13.02.2013</span>

$('.day_field').on('click',function(){
    var date = $(this).data("date");
    var task_id = $(this).data("task");
    //place for some validation
    $.post('book_task.php',{task_id: task_id, date: date},function(data){
        //something cool with the result
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 note that even if it is labeled as an html5 feature, it will work with old browsers just fine.

Comment: This seems perfect. I have to try it first in the company where i work because there are some users only with IE8 and i have to be sure it works properly. Please, tell me: Is it ok that the ID of the task is shown there and everyone can see it in the code? I am sure every hacker will find out what the number means, the question is if he can use it to do some bad stuff or not. Thanks!

Comment: Older browsers just treat these as custom attributes, which they just ignore. All that HTML5 did was reserve names beginning with `data-` to applications, so that you can be sure they'll never conflict with standard attributes. I'm not sure what the concern about hackers is -- the date attribute corresponds to the calendar date, there's nothing secret about it.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The right way</strike>A better way to do it would be to store the data in either data attributes, or make the span an anchor tag and store the param string desired in the href attribute.

```
<span class="day_field" data-date="13-02-2013" data-task="4>13.02.2013</span>

or

<a class="day-field" href="?task_id=4&date=13-02-2013">13.02.2013</a>
```

with this for the anchor tag:

```
$('.day_field').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("foo.php",this.href,handler);
});
```

Comment: I'd also add the data attributes to the anchor.

Comment: var date = $(this).prop("data-date");
var task_id = $(this).prop("data-task");

to access the values

Comment: @iAmClownShoe data-task is an attribute, not a property. That code was already covered in another answer, i don't see the need to repeat it

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an ID, you can use custom [data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/), like this:

```
<span class="day_field" data-date="date_13-02-2013_task_4">13.02.2013</span>
```

And then you can access the value like this in jQuery:

```
$(".day_field").data("date");
```

Answer (score 0):

Exposing the actual ID of something in your database is only as insecure as your database.

Using the `id` of the element seems fine to me, too, if it uniquely identifies a thing. Using the `data` attributes is a possibility to save on splitting logic if you like, but you could still use `id` in tandem.

Conventionally speaking, this is very tame code compared to much of what jQuery is.

Answer (score 0):

One more elegant way to associate data to an element is to use [jQuery's data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/). However, I would consider building a jQuery plugin and using one instance of it for each task. A plugin encapsulates all of the data it needs, so you wouldn't need to store it tied to the element, which is not great.